# Create Custom Cloning Button - New Admin

Tags: custom-button, clone

I am relatively new to salesforce and administration. I am trying to create a custom cloning button that checks against the user profile name.

I am using URL as content source.

```
if({$Profile.Name}="System Administrator") {
    /{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there. 
Try this:

```
if('{!$Profile.Name}'=='System Administrator') {
    window.location = '/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1';
}
```

Note the differences

- I am using the salesforce token evaluation syntax `{!}` around the `!Profile.Name` var. If you don't do this, it won't be evaluated by Salesforce.
- Also, I have enclosed that whole expression in quotes - we are comparing strings.
- Finally, I am using Javascript to redirect, so you need to use the `window.location` command to redirect.

This is tested and works for an onclick Javascript button.

Comment: If this worked for you, you can mark as accepted.

Comment: @casper I tried the above but the button is taking me to https://e/?clone=1

Comment: Check that you are in the opportunity context. Also check that you have correctly quoted the string. You can paste code snippet in a comment here if you like.